# How to call java from javascript in Wicket 6.0

Tags: java, wicket

There is many solutions how to do that in Wicket 1.5 and older, but how to do it in Wicket 6.0? Do anybody know any complete tutorial for that?

Answer (score 1):

Same as in 1.5, just replace wicketAjaxGet() with Wicket.Ajax.get({...}).
See what Wicket produces in the final markup for your page, look for Wicket.Ajax.ajax().
Check https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Wicket+Ajax for more.